# Microchip 23LC1024 driver for Atmel XMega

Tags: atmega, memory, microchip, sram, xmega

Is there driver or any example code available for 23LC1024 SRAM memory implemented with Atmel XMega or mega-series microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

Application note [AVR107, "Interfacing AVR microcontrollers with serial memories"](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/atmel.docs/atmel.docs.33080.21360.html), covers interfacing with 25XX devices. With a few modifications the code can be made to work with 23XX devices instead.